# How Do I Set An HTML Attribute For a Scala List Item Using Lift CSS Selectors?

Tags: scala, css-selectors, lift

I have some Lift code that creates table rows from a List:

```
".row *" #> myList.map(x => {
  val rowId = x.id

  ".cell1" #> x.data &
  ".cell2" #> x.moreData 
})
```

Based on a template like this:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell1"></td>
    <td class="cell2"></td>
  <tr>
<table>
```

I want output like this:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row" id="123">
    <td class="cell1">stuff</td>
    <td class="cell2">junk</td>
  <tr>
  <tr class="row" id="456">
    <td class="cell1">more stuff</td>
    <td class="cell2">more junk</td>
  <tr>
<table>
```

How do I set that `id` attribute to be `rowId` for each `tr` based on my List elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
".row" #> myList.map(x => {
  val rowId = x.id

  "tr [id]" #> rowId &
  ".cell1 *" #> x.data &
  ".cell2 *" #> x.moreData 
})
```

To set an attribute, you usually just need to specify the name of the attribute inside of `[]`. So, in addition to `ID`, if you wanted to add a class, it would be `[class]`. There is also a special modifier, `+` which will append to the current value. So `[class+]` will add whatever you specify to the current values.

It is also worth noting that some drafts of the HTML spec require at least one letter in the `ID`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) for an explanation of why.

Comment: That seems to change/add ids to elements inside the tr element.  I need thing the id to be added to each <tr class="row"></tr>, but not the <td>s or anything else inside.

Comment: @DorkRawk I updated the code to anchor only on the `TR` for the id. That will not add the `ID` attribute the children `TD` elements.

Comment: @jcern No, that will only affect tr elements inside the .row (which is a tr).  I need to append an id to the tr.

Comment: @VasyaNovikov Yes, I know I can do that, but what is the best way to make that work with pulling data from a List?

Comment: @DorkRawk, notice I dropped the ".row *" which you had in favor of ".row". That will pass the `TR` into the transform, not just the children.

Comment: @jcern You're right! That was my issue.  I needed to work with the whole tr, not just the contents.  Thanks.

Comment: @DorkRawk I suppose you already managed to do this. I just added a minor note that you can use `.row [id]` just like other selectors `.cell1 *`